# How do I run this aframe boilerplate code locally with https instead of http?

Tags: node.js, localhost, augmented-reality, aframe, budo

I'm a newbie so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I was trying to setup this a-frame boilerplate code.

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-boilerplate

This is the instructions given.

> To serve the site from a simple Node development server:
>
> npm start Then launch the site from your favourite browser:
>
> http://localhost:3000/

This works as expected, but the webcam is restricted because the site is http and not https. I want to know how to serve this as https instead?

Furthermore I am confused on what actually happens when you do `npm start`.

The start script is `budo --live --verbose --port 3000 --open`.

But the project doesn't have any js files that could be the server. Only the html file in the front end. What actually happens with npm start?

Answer (score 0):

npm start runs:

```
"start": "budo --live --verbose --port 3000 --open",
```

- running [budo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/budo) starts the server
- --live enables LiveReload on HTML/CSS/JS file changes
- --verbose enables debug messages
- --port defines the port
- --open launches the browser once connected
- by default it uses *index.html* which is in the main directory

If you want to create a https server instead of http you need to add one more option:

```
--ssl, -S        create an HTTPS server instead of HTTP
```

If you see some unknown commands run, always try to find the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/budo) and search the keywords (like HTTPS).

Comment: I added `--ssl, -S` to the command but still browser says Not Secure.

Comment: What OS, and browser are you at ? The [official gh](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo/blob/dcbc05866f583e172d6b46c898048436ab84ddae/docs/command-line-usage.md#ssl-and-https) says you might need to add an exception when on chrome, or generate your own certificate when working on iOS.

Comment: I'm on macos using chrome.